# 'Fatal error call to private method' but method is protected

Tags: php, oop

First time extending a class in PHP and I'm getting a fatal error that says the method is private when it's not. I'm sure it's something elementary, but I've studied books and forums, and I just can't pin down what I've done to generate this error. Any help greatly appreciated. Details below:

Error message:

> > Fatal error: Call to private method testgiver::dbConnect() from context 'testprinter' in /root/includes/classes/testprinter.php on line 726

Line 726 of testprinter in the code below:

```
private function buildquestionarray()
{
  $query = "etc etc";
  **$conn = $this->dbConnect('read');
  $result = $conn->query($query);
  ...
```

Testprinter extends testgiver. Here's the extension of the class:

```
require_once('testgiver.php');

class testprinter extends testgiver
{...
```

And the declaration of the method in testgiver:

```
protected function dbConnect($userconnecttype)
{...
```

Thanks again!

Comment: but the error is not because of the protected modifier of dbConnect(), but because of the private modifier of buildquestionarray().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already `Alexander Larikov` said that you can't access `protected methods` from class instance but not only `protected` methods but also you can't access `private` methods from class instance. To access a `protected` method of a `parent class` from the instance of a `subclass` you declare a `public method` in the subclass and then call the `protected method` of the `parent class` from the public method of the subclass, i.e.

```
class testgiver{
    protected function dbConnect($userconnecttype)
    {
        echo "dbConnect called with the argument ".$userconnecttype ."!";
    }
}

class testprinter extends testgiver
{
    public function buildquestionarray() // public instead of private so you can call it from the class instance
    {
        $this->dbConnect('read');
   }
}

$tp=new testprinter();
$tp->buildquestionarray(); // output: dbConnect called with the argument read!
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EgmOzU)

Comment: I think you have a type *"you can't access **protected** methods from class instance but not only **protected** methods"*

Comment: but the error is not because of the protected modifier of dbConnect(), but because of the private modifier of buildquestionarray().

Answer (score 0):

You can't access protected methods from class instance. Read [documentation](http://php.net/protected) which says `Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes`

Comment: but the error is not because of the protected modifier of dbConnect(), but because of the private modifier of buildquestionarray().

Answer (score 0):

The Alpha, great write-up!

I feel like I've almost got it where I want it, but am getting

```
Fatal Error, call to undefined method NameofClass::myFunction() in line 123456
```

Is there something I am missing here?

My original class, and the extending class are both in the same .php file, but the call to myFunction is happening in a different file. Is that not allowed?

**NOTE:** I would put this in a comment, but the system won't let me include comments until I have a reputation of 50.

Comment: but the error is not because of the protected modifier of dbConnect(), but because of the private modifier of buildquestionarray().